# Term for matrix $(a_{ij})$ where $a_{ij} = \overline{a_{ji}}$ for a field automorphism $\overline{\dot{}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

Given a matrix $(a_{ij})$ of a field $F$ that satisfies $a_{ij} = \overline{a_{ji}}$ for all $i, j$, where $\bar{\dot{}}$ is a field automorphism on $F$, is there a specific term for this property of the matrix?

For example, when $F = \mathbb{C}$ and $\overline{\dot{}}$ denotes complex conjugation, such a matrix is called Hermitian.

I'm asking because, if I'm not mistaken on this, if the Gram matrix $\Gamma_B(\sigma)$ of a $\overline{\dot{}}$-sesquilinear form $\sigma$ regarding a basis $B$ of the underlying vector space has the aforementioned property, then $\sigma$ should be symmetric. Edit: I was mistaken and for this to be true $\overline{\dot{}}$ also has to be an involution, i.e. $\bar{\bar{\dot{}}} = \text{id}_F$.